# how to extend function in jaggery

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have made emm works, and start with mysql.

I am trying to add more features, like cache.

If I want to add cache capability, like put data into memcached, how do I add a new function?

Answer (score 0):

I have found source code of ScriptableObject, like Log, Database, File. I can change those files and recompile them, but I cannot put into emm to make it run. 
Because I only can find source code of org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db_0.9.0.ALPHA4_wso2v1.jar. and emm needs rg.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db_0.9.0.ALPHA4_wso2v3.jar.

I have tried to search svn from wso2. But still cannot find 0.9.0.ALPHA4.wso2v3 source code. Anybody has any idea where is it?